# Mount Job Directory as Copy-on-Write

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-volume

I’m working on a build system and have a master job that spawns other child jobs (ie build, deploy, etc).

I am currently downloading the repo in the master job and would like to share the directory as copy-on-write to the other child jobs. This reduces network requests and should be faster than downloading multiple times. The changes, however, of the child job should not influence the parent’s job.

Typically, I’d just use a Docker COPY but Kaniko doesn’t allow  custom images. I’m considering an additional container that has the data copied over and then having Kaniko mount to that.

I’m fairly new to K8s, so this may not be the idiomatic way of doing things.

Thank you so much!